# Can't parse long numeric string as value with Helm

Tags: image, docker, tags, repository, kubernetes-helm

I want to set docker image repository and tag values from outside with `--set`. In my deployment manifest yaml file I wrote:

```
image: "{{ .Values.image.awesomeapp.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.awesomeapp.tag | quote }}"
```

And run `Helm` this way:

```
helm install charts/awesomeapp \
    --set image.awesomeapp.repository=1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/awesomeapp \
    --set image.awesomeapp.tag=20180131010101
```

But failed:

```
Failed to apply default image tag "1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/awesomeapp:\"2.01801310101013e+13\"": couldn't parse image reference "1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/orange-battle:\"2.01801310101013e+13\"": invalid reference format
```

Why it can’t pause image tag correctly?

Comment: The tag is being interpreted as an integer, maybe `--set image.awesomeapp.tag="20180131010101"`?

Answer (score 7):

It is a helm [bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1707):

> `helm install --set tag=20161216` ends up in scientific notation in
>   the template and that's because `{{ typeOf .Value.tag }}` yields
>   `float64`.

It is already fixed and [Adding --set-string flag to force string values](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/pull/3599) pull request is merged. So new flag `--set-string` will be added to `helm` some time later.

If you had to use old version `helm`, there could be the following workaround:

**1.** Deployment manifest yaml file should be changed to:

```
image: {{ .Values.image.awesomeapp.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.awesomeapp.tag | replace ":" "" }}
```

**2.** We need to define this extra symbol `:` before the value with `--set`:

```
helm install charts/awesomeapp \
    --set image.awesomeapp.repository=1234567890.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/awesomeapp \
    --set image.awesomeapp.tag=:20180131010101
```